# Google API - List Users that Reacted with Emoji in Google Meeting?

Tags: google-api, google-meet

We had a recent meeting, and management wants to know what users reacted with emoji's in the google meeting. I haven't found much in the docs that would give us the list of users, unless there's another link?

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/meet